# R function returns "Object not found" but variable does exist

Tags: r, function

This basic code should say everything:

```
df = data.frame(var1 = c("A","B","C"), var2 = c(1,2,3))
df
# var1 var2
# 1    A    1
# 2    B    2
# 3    C    3


newfunc = function(data = df, IV, DV){
  IV
  DV
}

newfunc(data = df, IV = var1, DV = var2)
# Error in print(IV) : object 'var1' not found
```

I must be overlooking something obvious - what is missing here?

Comment: var1 is a variable in df, use df$var1 instead..

Comment: You might be confusing tidyeval syntax with other base R code. Your function doesn't know to expect that var1 would be a column in that data frame. What exactly are you expecting the function to do?

Comment: @camille Yes you're right, I assumed that data = df would imply attach(df) so the variables would be identified properly.

Comment: @JovanGeraldyCandra Yes this is the simplest answer that works. It seems verbose to invoke df$ for each variable, but that is not so bad.

Comment: Attaching your data is probably not a good idea—it makes it hard to track what's in your environment, hard to debug, and likely to lead to conflicts such as if you have 2 data frames attached that have any of the same column names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var1` exists, but not in the environment you're calling the function from, it only exists inside `df`. You'd have to explicitly evaluate using `df` as an environment to get the intended effect here, with something like this:

```r
df = data.frame(var1 = c("A","B","C"), var2 = c(1,2,3))

newfunc = function(data = df, IV, DV){
  eval(substitute(IV), data)
}

newfunc(data = df, IV = var1, DV = var2)
#> [1] "A" "B" "C"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Or using `rlang` to make `IV` into a quosure first to eval later you could write it as below. It may be informative to read [Chapter 20 of Advanced R, "Evaluation"](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/evaluation.html)

```r
df = data.frame(var1 = c("A","B","C"), var2 = c(1,2,3))

library(rlang)

newfunc = function(data = df, IV, DV){
  IV <- new_quosure(substitute(IV), as_environment(data))
  eval_tidy(IV)
}

newfunc(data = df, IV = var1, DV = var2)
#> [1] "A" "B" "C"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

The function will be easier to write if you just pass `IV` as a string when you call the function though

```r
df = data.frame(var1 = c("A","B","C"), var2 = c(1,2,3))

newfunc = function(data = df, IV, DV){
  data[[IV]]
}

newfunc(data = df, IV = 'var1')
#> [1] "A" "B" "C"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: It seems that the function as you wrote it would not generalize to other datasets, since df is explicitly called within it. If I use "data" rather than "df", it doesn't work.

Comment: Disregard my previous comment, you were right. Thanks for the note. I've corrected the answer.

Comment: It does work with `data` in the function body though

Comment: You are right, I did not notice two things: 1) the double brackets, and 2) the quoted variable name in the function call. I am not familiar with the double bracket paradigm, but it does work, and avoids having to repeatedly invoke df$.

Answer (score 1):

Credit to Jovan Geraldy Candra in the comments, posting his answer here with added detail for posterity.

"var1 is a variable in df, use df$var1 instead"

Indeed:

```
df = data.frame(var1 = c("A","B","C"), var2 = c(1,2,3))
df
# var1 var2
# 1    A    1
# 2    B    2
# 3    C    3


newfunc = function(data = df, IV, DV){
  IV
  DV
}

newfunc(data = df, IV = df$var1, DV = df$var2)
```

To be clear, the function body should have read print(IV) and print(DV) to output the data properly. But with df$ the data does output as expected.

I had incorrectly assumed that df$ was not necessary due to data = df, due to my previous experience with `lm(data=df, DV~IV)` not needing df$ repeated. It seems this paradigm does not apply within functions.

Answer (score 0):

var1 and var2 are not defined as variables, but are columns of the dataframe df.
You can check all existing variables in your environment by using

```
ls()
```

I am sure you will find neither var1 nor var2.
To fix your code, you could declare these variables before assigning them to columns of the dataframe. But I am not really sure what you are trying to achieve in the end.

```
var1_vector = c("A","B","C")
var2_vector = c(1,2,3)

df = data.frame(var1 = var1_vector, var2 = var2_vector)
df
# var1 var2
# 1    A    1
# 2    B    2
# 3    C    3


newfunc = function(data = df, IV, DV){
  IV
  DV
}

newfunc(data = df, IV = var1_vector, DV = var2_vector)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work: -

```
df = data.frame(var1 = c("A","B","C"), var2 = c(1,2,3))
df
# var1 var2
# 1    A    1
# 2    B    2
# 3    C    3
```

The columns of the data frame can be renamed by specifying the new column names as a vector. The new name replaces the corresponding old name of the column in the data frame. The length of new column vector should be equivalent to the number of columns originally. Changes are made to the original data frame.

```
# printing original data frame
print("Original data frame : ")
print(df)
  
print("Renaming columns names ")
  
# assigning new names to the columns of the data frame
colnames(df) <- c('IV','DV')
  
# printing new data frame
print("New data frame : ")
print(df)
```

OUTPUT: -

```
[1] "New data frame : "
  IV DV
1  A  1
2  B  2
3  C  3
```

Answer (score -1):

I had some luck with this:

```
df = data.frame(var1 = c("A","B","C"), var2 = c(1,2,3))
df
# var1 var2
# 1    A    1
# 2    B    2
# 3    C    3


newfunc = function(data = df, IV, DV){
  df[,IV]
  df[,DV]
}

# Error in print(IV) : object 'var1' not found
newfunc(df )
```